# Windows 7 Chromium Embedded Framework - override mouse clicks

Tags: c#, windows, chromium-embedded

I need to ignore all right clicks within my application and Chromium Embedded Framework.

Now I had this working great on an old version which used the WebBrowser widget, but now after switching over to CEF browser, the KeyMessageFilter does not get the message when the CEF browser is in focus. The first related post seems to say that the CEF keeps hold of the event and does not pass it on to the application.

However, I don't understand the answer. It seems to be in Basic or something....

Here is my KeyMessageFilter code

```
public class KeyMessageFilter : IMessageFilter
{
    private enum KeyMessages
    {
        WM_KEYFIRST = 0x100,
        WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100,
        WM_KEYUP = 0x101,
        WM_CHAR = 0x102,
        WM_SYSKEYDOWN = 0x0104,
        WM_SYSKEYUP = 0x0105,
        WM_SYSCHAR = 0x0106,
        WM_MOUSEWHEEL = 0x20a
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr GetParent(IntPtr hwnd);

    // We check the events agains this control to only handle
    // key event that happend inside this control.
    Control _control;

    public KeyMessageFilter()
    { }

    public KeyMessageFilter(Control c)
    {
        _control = c;
    }

    public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
    {

        Console.WriteLine(m.Msg);

        // Filter out WM_NCRBUTTONDOWN/UP/DBLCLK
        if (m.Msg == 0xA4 || m.Msg == 0xA5 || m.Msg == 0xA6) return true;
        // Filter out WM_RBUTTONDOWN/UP/DBLCLK
        if (m.Msg == 0x204 || m.Msg == 0x205 || m.Msg == 0x206) return true;

        if (m.Msg == (int)KeyMessages.WM_MOUSEWHEEL)
        {
            if (Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Control)
            {
                return true;
            }

        }

        if (m.Msg == (int)KeyMessages.WM_KEYDOWN)
        {
            if (_control != null)
            {
                IntPtr hwnd = m.HWnd;
                IntPtr handle = _control.Handle;
                while (hwnd != IntPtr.Zero && handle != hwnd)
                {
                    hwnd = GetParent(hwnd);
                }
                if (hwnd == IntPtr.Zero) // Didn't found the window. We are not interested in the event.
                    return false;
            }

            Keys key = (Keys)m.WParam;

            if (key.Equals(Keys.Tab))
            {
                return true;
            }

            if (Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Control)
            {

                switch (key)
                {

                    case Keys.Oemplus:
                        return true;
                    case Keys.OemMinus:
                        return true;

                }

            }

        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

#### Related Posts

- Ignoring keys in winAPi: Stack Overflow question *[Override mouse using Chromium embedded framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8712974)*
- Ignoring keys: Stack Overflow question *[How to detect the currently pressed key?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1927644/1312937)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay here is how I did it.

I used a low level hook for the mouse in the Program.cs file.
I then used a Setting to say wether my App is focused or not this uses the Form.Activated / Deactivated events (other wise it would swallow all right clicks on the computer while the App is running, BAD EXPERIENCE).

Relevant Links:[Global mouse event handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11607133/global-mouse-event-handler)

Program.cs

```
 private static LowLevelMouseProc _proc = HookCallback;
    private static IntPtr _hookID = IntPtr.Zero;

Main(string[] args){

.......
  _hookID = SetHook(_proc);

            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new ContainerForm());


       UnhookWindowsHookEx(_hookID);

}



    private static IntPtr SetHook(LowLevelMouseProc proc)
    {
        using (Process curProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
        using (ProcessModule curModule = curProcess.MainModule)
        {
            return SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, proc,
                GetModuleHandle(curModule.ModuleName), 0);
        }
    }

    private delegate IntPtr LowLevelMouseProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    private static IntPtr HookCallback(
        int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {

        if (nCode >= 0 &&
            (MouseMessages.WM_RBUTTONDOWN == (MouseMessages)wParam || MouseMessages.WM_RBUTTONUP == (MouseMessages)wParam))
        {
            //If the app has focuse swallow event
            if (Properties.Settings.Default.AppFocus) {

                return new IntPtr(-1);

            }
            else
            {
                return CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);

            }

        }

        return CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }

    private const int WH_MOUSE = 7;

    private const int WH_MOUSE_LL = 14;

    private enum MouseMessages
    {
        WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201,
        WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x0202,
        WM_MOUSEMOVE = 0x0200,
        WM_MOUSEWHEEL = 0x020A,
        WM_RBUTTONDOWN = 0x0204,
        WM_RBUTTONUP = 0x0205
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct POINT
    {
        public int x;
        public int y;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct MSLLHOOKSTRUCT
    {
        public POINT pt;
        public uint mouseData;
        public uint flags;
        public uint time;
        public IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook,
        LowLevelMouseProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode,
        IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);

}
```

Form.cs

```
 private void onActivated(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {

             Properties.Settings.Default.AppFocus = true;

         }

         private void onDeactivated(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
             Properties.Settings.Default.AppFocus = false;

         }
```

This likely isn't the best way to do this, however I was unable to get the CEFBrowser object to ignore right clicks, just as I was unable to get the Form as a whole to ignore right clicks, or even the Application to ignore (non-low level) Mouse Events. This is the work around of someone who is completely new to Windows so don't take this as the best code ever but it is working for me.